# Kubuntu 23.04 hangs at boot for ~90 seconds

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 23.04

I'm experiencing a ~90 seconds hang when booting a fresh install of Kubuntu 23.04 using a encrypted LLVM volume created by the Kubuntu installer without further customization.

When the boot hangs, I'm seeing the Kubuntu splash screen.

Looking at output of dmesg, I don't know where to look further and would be happy for any pointers.
Excerpt from dmesg:

```
[snip]
[   10.101831] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[   10.101867] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[   10.101892] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[   10.101913] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[   10.101936] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
[   10.780731] loop0: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[   10.781940] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[   10.781992] loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 149488
[   10.782535] loop2: detected capacity change from 0 to 149720
[   10.782992] loop3: detected capacity change from 0 to 495928
[   10.785986] loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 498592
[   10.788070] loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 943224
[   10.790246] loop6: detected capacity change from 0 to 942872
[   10.792170] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 187776
[   10.794978] loop8: detected capacity change from 0 to 102072
[   10.796585] loop9: detected capacity change from 0 to 109032
[   10.831368] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.895:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=935 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.831461] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.895:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=937 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.831545] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.895:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/haveged" pid=941 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.831918] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.895:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=929 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.832420] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.899:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oosplash" pid=934 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.832524] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.899:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=930 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.832534] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.899:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=930 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.833457] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.899:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=932 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.833466] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.899:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=932 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.833473] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910795.899:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=932 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.058873] kauditd_printk_skb: 25 callbacks suppressed
[  100.058875] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910885.123:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="rsyslogd" pid=1008 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.076442] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910885.143:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1113 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  100.124379] RTL8226B_RTL8221B 2.5Gbps PHY r8169-0-500:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-500:00, irq=MAC)
[  100.324582] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[  100.590480] loop10: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[  102.660852] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  102.660863] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
[  102.662121] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  102.662146] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[  105.730946] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  115.464695] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910900.531:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19122/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1903 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  115.464702] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910900.531:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19122/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1903 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  115.675756] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910900.739:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=1944 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  115.675807] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910900.739:42): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=1944 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  115.675942] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910900.739:43): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=1944 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  115.675969] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910900.739:44): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=1944 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  116.335800] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910901.399:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=2014 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
[  116.335896] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910901.399:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=2014 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
[  116.335930] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910901.399:47): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=2014 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
[  116.335980] audit: type=1400 audit(1684910901.399:48): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=2014 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
[snip]
```

I'm seeing `apparmor="DENIED"` regarding cupsd in the vicinity. Could this somehow be related to the delay?

Comment: Try editing "nosplash" (without the quotes) into the "vmlinuz" command in the GRUB startup and watch for a start job counting down during that 90 second freeze period -- and report back what the start job is for.

Comment: I booted with nosplash. After unlocking the encrypted volume, the last two lines I'm seeing when booting hangs are `cryptsetup [...] set up successfully` and `/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root: clean, x/y files, z blocks`. Then it hangs.

Comment: I set pass to 0 in /etc/fstab to exclude fsck as a possible culprit, btw.

Comment: Found it. I also removed "quiet" from the vmlinuz command and then had some more information: The hanging job was `job dev-disk-by\` followed by something looking like a UUID. I did not find that UUID in /etc/fstab, but in /etc/crypttab. It belonged to an external backup hdd that was once mounted and then removed again, but somehow created a permanent entry in /etc/crypttab. Of course mounting that non-existing drive couldn't work. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction!

Comment: Sounds like you should write a self-answer.  Then you can get some rep for this.  :)